# Stabilization of the ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, stability-theory

Can you help me with next problems?

1. Find controls $u_2, u_2$ for system 
   $$\left\{
   \begin{array}{c}
    x_1'=ax_2x_3, \\
    x_2'=bx_1x_3 +u_2, \\
   x_3'=cx_1x_2 +u_3, \\
   \end{array}
   \right.$$
   using back-steping, for stabilization of the point $(0,0,0)$ (asymptotic stable), where $a>0, b>0, c>0$.

   2. Prove, that  system 
      $$\left\{
      \begin{array}{c}
       x_1'=ax_2x_3, \\
       x_2'=bx_1x_3, \\
      x_3'=cx_1x_2 +u_3, \\
      \end{array}
      \right.$$
      are unstable (means point $(0,0,0)$) for any control $u_3$.

   Thanks!

Comment: The first system is not lower triangular. Are you sure there is no typo?

Comment: No. First system are correct

Comment: @AVK you could bring it into a triangular for by defining $u_2 = v_2 - b\,x_1\,x_3$ and $u_3 = v_3 - c\,x_1\,x_2$ with $v_2$ and $v_3$ new virtual inputs, and considering $x_1$ as the last coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

The second system is not stabilizable because it has a first integral. Consider
$$
V(x_1,x_2,x_3)= bx_1^2-ax_2^2;
$$
for any $u$ the derivative along the trajectories
$$
\dot V= 2bx_1 \dot x_1-2a x_2\dot x_2= 2abx_1x_2x_3-2abx_1x_2x_3=0.
$$
**Update:** As @Kwin van der Veen has suggested in his comment, you can substitute the variables $u_2=v_2-bx_1x_3$, $u_3=v_3-cx_1x_2$ and obtain
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
\dot x_1&=&ax_2x_3\\
\dot x_2&=&v_2\\
\dot x_3&=&v_3.
\end{array}\right.
$$
The subsystem $\dot x_1=ax_2x_3$ is stabilized by, among other, $x_2=-x_1$, $x_3=x_1^2$. Introduce the new variables $z_2= x_2+x_1$, $z_3=x_3-x_1^2$:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
\dot x_1&=&a(z_2-x_1)(z_3+x_1^2)\\
\dot z_2&=&\dot x_1+\dot x_2=a(z_2-x_1)(z_3+x_1^2)+v_2\\
\dot z_3&=&\dot x_3-2x_1\dot x_1= v_3-2ax_1(z_2-x_1)(z_3+x_1^2)
\end{array}\right.
$$
and consider the Lyapunov function $V(x_1,z_2,z_3)=\frac12x_1^2+\frac12z_2^2+\frac12z_3^2$. The derivative
$$
\dot V= x_1\dot x_1+z_2\dot z_2+z_3\dot z_3= ax_1(z_2-x_1)(z_3+x_1^2)
$$
$$+
z_2 (a(z_2-x_1)(z_3+x_1^2)+v_2)+z_3(v_3-2ax_1(z_2-x_1)(z_3+x_1^2))=\ldots
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you. What about first system?

Comment: @I.M.V. See my update

Comment: Thank you!
I will try to continue calculations.